# Referencing beans in xml config created via Annotations

Tags: spring

This must be possible but I can't work out how or see it in the docs.

I need to reference a bean which has been created via an annotation @Service and context:component-scan, within a spring xml config file.

How is this achieved?

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. use `@Service("myService")`
2. in the xml, use `<property name="myProperty" ref="myService"/>`

Comment: +1, though #1 is not strictly necessary. Default name will be set to uncapitalized unqualified class name; naming strategy can also be explicitly specified via `BeanNameGenerator`.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't this the same as using @Service and a class named MyService? I'm pretty sure that's what I'm doing. Will check tomorrow when I'm back at the codebase.

Comment: As ChssPly mentioned, it is the _uncapitalized_ class nam. So "MyClass" would be referenced as "myClass"

Comment: I know, that's what i meant. Class MyService, @Service, ref="myService".

Cheers